# Deserialize tuple value life time issue

Tags: rust, tuples, lifetime

When I try to deserialise a value inside a tuple, it won't allow me to push the result into an array.

```
fn main() {
    let raw_value = vec![(1, ("a", "a", 1))];

    //serialise
    let mut serialized_value = vec![];

    for val in raw_value.iter() {
        serialized_value.push((
            bincode::serialize(&val.0).unwrap(),
            bincode::serialize(&val.1).unwrap(),
        ));
    }

    //deserialise
    let mut deserialized_value: Vec<(&str, &str, i32)> = vec![];

    for val in serialized_value {
        deserialized_value.push(bincode::deserialize(&val.1).unwrap());
    }
}
```

It issues the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `val.1` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:54
   |
18 |         deserialized_value.push(bincode::deserialize(&val.1).unwrap());
   |         ---------------------------------------------^^^^^^-----------
   |         |                                            |
   |         |                                            borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         borrow later used here
19 |     }
   |     - `val.1` dropped here while still borrowed
```

But this works fine if I refactor the value to not be inside a tuple.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating destructively through `serialized_value`.
Because of that, after the given loop iteration ends, the `val` is dropped and after the whole loop the `serialized_value` is fully consumed.

If you iterate through `&serialized_value` instead, then the `val` will be reference to the element in the container and `serialized_value` will be kept alive on the stack, because it's being referenced.

Comment: Spot on, thanks! However how come I am allowed to do this if the original value is not a tuple?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @miszcz2137's answer, here is the working version:

```rust
fn main() {
    let raw_value = vec![(1, ("a", "a", 1))];

    //serialise
    let mut serialized_value = vec![];

    for val in raw_value.iter() {
        serialized_value.push((
            bincode::serialize(&val.0).unwrap(),
            bincode::serialize(&val.1).unwrap(),
        ));
    }

    //deserialise
    let mut deserialized_value: Vec<(&str, &str, i32)> = vec![];

    for val in &serialized_value {
        deserialized_value.push(bincode::deserialize(&val.1).unwrap());
    }

    println!("{:?}", deserialized_value);
}
```

```
[("a", "a", 1)]
```

---

That said, it's not quite idiomatic to fill a vector through a `for` loop. It's much better practice to use iterators and `.collect()`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let raw_value = vec![(1, ("a", "a", 1))];

    //serialise
    let serialized_value: Vec<_> = raw_value
        .iter()
        .map(|val| {
            (
                bincode::serialize(&val.0).unwrap(),
                bincode::serialize(&val.1).unwrap(),
            )
        })
        .collect();

    //deserialise
    let deserialized_value: Vec<(&str, &str, i32)> = serialized_value
        .iter()
        .map(|val| bincode::deserialize(&val.1).unwrap())
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", deserialized_value);
}
```

```
[("a", "a", 1)]
```

Comment: thank you! I will refactor my code. It takes a while to get into the mind set of iterators :/